# Craft beers and Microbreweries in Pittsburgh?

Tags: breweries, local

Are there local micro-breweries in Pittsburgh?

What are craft beers that one can find only in Pittsburgh?

On https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_breweries_in_Pennsylvania#Southwestern_Pennsylvania, there's a list of breweries but they don't look like microbrews =(

There's a longer list on https://pittsburghbreweries.com/. Have anyone visited all 30+ breweries? Which of them are craft beer brews? Or are they all craft breweries?

Interestingly Rochefort 10 is rated top beer in Pittsburgh, can any steelers verify this? https://www.ratebeer.com/BestInMyArea.asp?CountryID=213&StateID=38

Comment: You might want to search on the Beer Advocate site for Pittsburg. https://www.beeradvocate.com/search/?q=pittsburg

Comment: They make a Yinser App for that, don't they?

Comment: BTW, what's an Yinser?

Comment: I think a Yinzer is someone from Pittsburgh.

Comment: [Bier's Pub & War Streets Brewery](https://maps.app.goo.gl/D32AtJYsv721H69n7) or [Grist House Craft Brewery](https://maps.app.goo.gl/eQc4frLmVrr23ELi8) may fit? Never been to the US unfortunately...but Google Maps is our very friend ;)

Comment: @EricS - Not just anybody from the burgh, "N'at"  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yinzer  N’at = and that. https://www.pghcitypaper.com/pittsburgh/pittsburghese-dictionary-how-to-translate-the-yinzer-vocabulary/Content?oid=14838287

Answer (score 2):

A search on Google Maps gave me these results:

- [Bier's Pub & War Streets Brewery](https://bierspub.com/war-streets-brewery)
- [Brew Gentlemen](https://www.brewgentlemen.com/) (in Braddock, PA)
- [Dancing Gnome Beer](http://www.dancinggnomebeer.com/home/)
- [Grist House Craft Brewery](https://gristhouse.com/)
- [Hop Farm Brewing Company](https://www.hopfarmbrewingco.com/)
- [Penn Brewery](https://www.pennbrew.com/)
- [Roundabout Brewery](https://roundaboutbeer.com/)
- [Southern Tier Brewery](https://stbcbeer.com/)
- [Spring Hill Brewing](https://www.springhillbrewing.com/)

...and very probably many other local ones producing a few hundred liters per time!